# EUCA 4.4.5 VPCMIDO Instances Terminate at Launch

Tags: eucalyptus

I have achieved a small test cloud on 3 pieces of hardware.  It works fine when in EDGE mode but when I try to configure it for VPCMIDO, new instances begin to launch but then timeout and move to a terminated state. I can also see the instances' initial volume and config data appear in the NC and CC data directories.  Below is my system layout and network.json.

HOST 1 : CLC/UFS/WALRUS/MIDO CLUSTER/MIDO GATEWAY/MIDOLMAN AGENT:

em1 (All Services including Mido Cluster): 10.0.0.21

em3 (Target VPCMIDO Adapter): 10.0.0.22

HOST 2 : CC/SC

em1 : 10.0.0.23

HOST 3 : NC/MIDOLMAN AGENT

em1 : 10.0.0.24

```
{
    "Mido": {
        "Gateways": [
            {
                "Ip": "10.0.0.22",
                "ExternalDevice": "em3",
                "ExternalCidr": "192.168.0.0/16",
                "ExternalIp": "192.168.0.2",
                "ExternalRouterIp": "192.168.0.1"
            }
        ]
    },
    "Mode": "VPCMIDO",
    "PublicIps": [
        "10.0.100.1-10.0.100.254"
    ]
}
```

I may be misunderstanding the intent of reserving an interface just for the mido gateway.  All of my eucalyptus/zookeeper/cassandra/midonet configs use the 10.0.0.21 interface and seem to communicate fine.  The midonet tunnel zone reports my CLC host and NC host successfully in the tunnel zone.  The only part of my config that references the interface I intend to use for the midonet gateway is the network.json.  No errors were returned at any time during my config so I think I may be missing something conceptual.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I configured a bridge on the NC and instances were able to launch and I no longer got an error in my nc.log.  Docs and the eucalyptus.conf file comments tell me I shouldn't need to do this in VPCMIDO netowrking mode: https://docs.eucalyptus.cloud/eucalyptus/4.4.5/index.html#install-guide/configuring_bridge.html

Despite all that adding the bridge fixed this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to start eucanetd as described here:

https://docs.eucalyptus.cloud/eucalyptus/4.4.5/index.html#install-guide/starting_euca_clc.html

The eucanetd component in vpcmido mode runs on the cloud controller and is responsible for controlling midonet.

When eucanetd is not running instances will fail to start as the required network resources will not be created.

Comment: I just found this on my NC nc.log ```ERROR | libvirt: Cannot get interface MTU on 'br0': No such device (code=38)
2019-10-31 10:43:56 ERROR | [i-b01e3e36] hypervisor failed to create the instance```  I was under the impression that no bridge device was required on a NC and that the midolman agent tunneled client traffic out through the gateway.  Do I still need to do some sort of special network config on NC's even in VPCMIDO mode?  I think I may have been misled by this comment in the eucalyptus.conf ```(in VPCMIDO mode there is no
# need to attach this physical interface).```